# Trigger Authcache Reload on Field Change for Drupal Commerce Products

Tags: commerce, caching

I activated authcache and the cache system is working well.
When i change the price for a product the page is read from the cache.
How can i trigger to reload the page from database if one specific field (price field for example) is changed?

Information on my installation:

I have installed [Drupal Core 7.37](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.37-release-notes) , [Commerce 7.x-1.11.](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/releases/7.x-1.11) and [AuthCache 7.x-2.0-beta5](https://www.drupal.org/project/authcache/releases/7.x-2.0-beta5).

Answer (score 0):

Authcache comes with an integration module for the [Cache Expiration](https://www.drupal.org/project/expire) project. See also the [Authcache 2 tuning guide - integrate with Cache Expiration module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2158615).

It might get tricky to find all pages where a particular product/price is displayed due to the separation of products and display nodes in commerce. Depending on how frequent prices are changed, you might consider nuking the whole cache, e.g. using a combination of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and the [Cache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_actions) module.